# How do you use IPrincipal and IIdentity in the portable class libraries?

Tags: .net-4.5, wif, portable-class-library, iprincipal, iidentity

With WIF (Windows Identity Foundation) 4.5, Microsoft created the [`WindowsPrincipal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsprincipal.aspx) class, which is a type of [`ClaimsPrincipal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsprincipal.aspx). Of course, these classes aren't portable, but the interfaces behind them are (`IPrincipal`). The same can be said of the [`ClaimsIndentity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsidentity.aspx) class implementing the `IIdentity` interface.

The problem I have is that these classes, and WIF in general is based entirely on the concept of "claims", which is awesome... but the two interfaces, `IPrincipal` and `IIdentity` are not. Not only that, but the `ClaimsPrincipal` class also has a collection of Identities instead of just a single Identity associated to it.

- IPrincipal has `Identity` and `IsInRole` members.
- IIdentity has `AuthenticationType`, `IsAuthenticated`, and `Name` members.

Given the fact that the Portable Class Libraries can only access these two interfaces, how does one go about getting the actual claims?

Also, in the rare instance that a principal has multiple identities, how does one get the "non-primary" identities?

Comment: As you have said that every ClaimsPrincipal have multiple identities and every identity have collection of claims so you can access any identity by getting into the reference variable of ClaimsPrincipal.
Like ClaimsPrincipal.Identities[1] for the second non primary identity

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft provided claims aware types in `Microsoft.IdentityModel.dll` which is not portable (*yet*, I hope). Those types just extends current identity types e.g. `IPrincipal`:

```
public interface IClaimsPrincipal : IPrincipal
```

It means that claims aware types are compatibile with old code which uses `IPrincipal` and `IIdentity` interfaces. But to make your code *claims aware* you must add a reference to `Microsoft.IdentityModel.dll` (which is not available as a PCL) or write it from scratch.

If you want to test how old code behaves when processing instances of claims aware types, you can just use downcasting to the `IPrincipal` interface:

```
IClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new List<IClaimsIdentity>()
{
    new ClaimsIdentity("AuthType1"),
    new ClaimsIdentity("AuthType2")
});

IPrincipal principal = claimsPrincipal as IPrincipal;
IIdentity identity = principal.Identity;
```

Comment: FYI, The namespace Microsoft.IdentityModel isn't WIF 4.5. WIF 4.5 was included in .NET 4.5 so all the proper namespaces start with System. e.g. System.IdentityModel, System.Security.Claims. There are migration guides if you look around.